# HTML5 Video currentTime not updating in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-video

In Chrome, for some reason in a page, if I set `currentTime` for `<video id="player" preload="metadata" playsinline>` tag, it is not updating. For example, if I set `document.getElementById('player').currentTime = 5`, it is not updating. It starts playing from 0.

I added the same code in another page but it is working fine without any issues in Chrome. And in Firefox, both the pages are working fine.

FYI, I am trying to seek the video using custom video controls and setting the current time. Only in this case, it fails to work.

I don't know what is happening. Any advice please.

Comment: My guess would be that when you are setting the video element's `currentTime` it might not be ready yet

Answer (score 0):

You should load your video and only after that set .currentTime.

Try this:

```
let player = document.getElementById('player');
preload(player, 5);
function preload(elem, time){
 elem.setAttribute('preload', 'auto');
 elem.addEventListener('canplaythrough', setCurrentTime);
 function setCurrentTime(){
 elem.currentTime  = time;
 elem.setAttribute('preload','none');
 elem.removeEventListener('canplaythrough', setCurrentTime);
 }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to seek the video using custom video controls and setting the current time. Only in this case, it fails to work. I have edited this post a little bit for better understanding. Sorry for not detailing the post